# Reducible matrices and strongly connected graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

The incidence matrix below is primitive (the graph is strongly connected) thus it is irreducible. However, this matrix looks reducible (using $P = I_n$) ?!  What am I missing?

[A is called reducible if, subject to some permutation of the rows and the same permutation of the columns, A can be written in upper triangular block form, i.e. $$PAP^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix} B &C \\0 &D\end{bmatrix}$$]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the given matrix is irreducible. Your claim is correct that if a matrix is reducible, then it can be written in the form (after some reordering of the states):
$$A' = \begin{pmatrix} B & C\\ \color{blue}{\mathbf{0}} & D \end{pmatrix}.$$

But notice that $B$ and $D$ must be **square** blocks! Apparently, you think that the blue block represents the zero block above:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 &  * & * & * \\
0 & 0  &  * & * & *\\
  1 & 0 & * & * & *\\
\color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 & * & * & *\\
\color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 & * & * & *
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But the block above the blue block is not square!