# I wonder what is really a reducible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A = \begin{bmatrix}
 0&  1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1\\ 
 1&  0&  0& 0
\end{bmatrix}
According to Matrix Analysis 2nd edition Definition 6.2.21, this is a reducible matrix if I exchange column 1 and 3.
However, obviously $A$ is irreducible as $(A+I)^{n-1}>0$, and $A$ represents a strongly connected graph too.
I read this question: [Reducible matrices and strongly connected graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771406/reducible-matrices-and-strongly-connected-graphs). In the answer @thanasissdr mentioned that $B$ and $D$ must be square blocks. But my $A$ above is a $4\times4$ matrix and the result $B$ and $D$ are exactly square.
So this is what I'm confused: whether my $A$ is reducible or not?

Comment: You can apply the strong component algorithm to decide this, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315453/how-does-one-show-a-matrix-is-irreducible-and-reducible).

Comment: Thx a lot! but I want an exact math proof of this too..

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $M$ is *reducible* if there is a permutation matrix $P$ so that

$$PMP^T=\begin{bmatrix}B&C\\0&D\end{bmatrix}$$

where $B$ and $D$ are square.

On the other hand, $M$ is *partly decomposable* if there are permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ so that

$$PMQ=\begin{bmatrix}B&C\\0&D\end{bmatrix}$$

where $B$ and $D$ are square.

The matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 0&  1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1\\ 
 1&  0&  0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

happens to be partly decomposable, but not reducible.

You give a permutation $P^T$ of the columns so that $AP^T$ is of the form $\begin{bmatrix}B&C\\0&D\end{bmatrix}$, but for reducibility we need a simultaneous permutation of the rows and columns; $PAP^T$ must be of this form.